# flask_moment current time refresh in browser not updating

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2, momentjs

Following basic setup with python3.4, jinja2, flask_moment (0.5.1), Flask(0.10.1) integration. 
I am trying out the capability to simply understand the workings. 
The example is nonsensical but I want to get browser to display:

- firstly, the actual time in real time ("The local time is ...") continually updated in real time
- secondly, the time elapsed ("That was ...").

Jinja2 code:

```
    <p>The local time is {{ moment(current_time).format('LT', refresh=True) }}.</p>
    <p>That was {{ moment(current_time).fromNow(refresh=True) }}</p>
```

The second line refresh works fine in the browser ("That was 1/2/3 minutes ago"), indicating all libraries working correctly, but the first line refresh doesn't work.

The method moment(current_time).format('LT', refresh=True) I thought would display the time in real time with the refresh option set to "True", but it doesn't.

Looking at browser markup, all the libraries are there and there are no errors. See markup below. 
Any hints appreciated or maybe I am misunderstanding the capability?

Browser source:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Hello, Flask!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>The local time is <span class="flask-moment" data-timestamp="2016-01-28T12:19:20Z" data-format="format('LT')" data-refresh="60000" style="display: none">2016-01-28T12:19:20Z</span>.</p>
    <p>That was <span class="flask-moment" data-timestamp="2016-01-28T12:19:20Z" data-format="fromNow(0)" data-refresh="60000" style="display: none">2016-01-28T12:19:20Z</span></p>


   <script src="/static/bootstrap/jquery.min.js?bootstrap=3.3.5.7"></script>
   <script src="/static/bootstrap js/bootstrap.min.js?bootstrap=3.3.5.7"></script>
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     moment.locale("en");
     function flask_moment_render(elem) {
       $(elem).text(eval('moment("' + $(elem).data('timestamp') + '").' + $(elem).data('format') + ';'));
       $(elem).removeClass('flask-moment').show();
     }
     function flask_moment_render_all() {
       $('.flask-moment').each(function() {
       flask_moment_render(this);
       if ($(this).data('refresh')) {
         (function(elem, interval) { setInterval(function() { flask_moment_render(elem) }, interval); })(this, $(this).data('refresh'));
        }
    })
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    flask_moment_render_all();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a misunderstanding on how Flask-Moment works, probably due to my not very clear documentation.

The `moment(current_time).format('LT', refresh=True)` expression that you put in the Jinja template runs in the server, not the browser. In particular, the `current_time` variable has a fixed value that I presume you assigned in the Python code.

The result of running this expression is some Javascript code that runs on the browser. When you pass `refresh=True`, this Javascript code runs every minute. But while the code does run repeatedly, the rendered time is always the same, because a value for `current_time` was set on the server and isn't being updated. The use of auto-refresh only makes sense with one of the "dynamic" rendering options of moment.js, such as the "X secs/mins ago" format, because those change as time passes.

If you wanted to implement something like a clock, that updates the time, then you would probably need a solution that does it all in Javascript on the browser.

Comment: Miguel, Thanks for reply. Yes, I now understand and indeed have retrospectively coded it in javascript as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that according to the documentation, the refresh=true is only going to be updated every minute.  Have you given it a minute to verify that it's not refreshing?

> The rendered dates and times can be refreshed periodically by passing
>   a refresh = True argument to any of the above functions. This is
>   useful for the relative formats, because they are updated as time
>   passes. The refresh interval is fixed at one minute.

http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/flask-moment-flask-and-jinja2-integration-with-momentjs

Comment: Chris - yes indeed I have given it spades of time. The refresh time for both lines in the jinja script is the same and the second one updates as expected but not the first. Thanks.